# Undefined method in my app. What's wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try blocking Ip addresses in my app like this - [lifeonrails.org](http://lifeonrails.org/2007/8/26/blocking-ip-addresses-in-rails). I already have a module in /lib and model banned_ip.

Why I have this error below from views/banned_ips/index.html?

===My error:===

**NoMethodError in Admin/banned_ips#index**

*Showing app/views/admin/banned_ips/index.html.erb where line #9 raised:*

```
undefined method `banned?' for "127.0.0.1":String
```

*Extracted source (around line #9):*

```
6:     <th>Last_ip</th>
7:     <th>Date</th>
8:   </tr>
9: <% if request.remote_ip.banned? == true %>banned<% else %>ok<% end %>
10: <% for banned_ip in @banned_ips %>
11:   <tr>
12:     <td><%=h banned_ip.first_ip %></td>
```

---

===Module infrid.rb in /lib===

```
module Infrid
  class IPAddress
    include Comparable
    def initialize(address)
      @address = address
    end
    def split
      @address.split(‘.‘).map {|s| s.to_i }
    end
    def <=>(other)
      split <=> other.split
    end
    def to_s
      @address
    end
  end
end
```

---

===Model banned_ip:===

```
class BannedIp < ActiveRecord::Base
    @banned_ips # hash of ips and masks
    validates_presence_of :first_ip, :message =>"first address is needed"
    validates_presence_of :last_ip, :message =>"last address is needed"
    validates_format_of :first_ip, :with => REG_IP, :message => "is invalid (must be x.x.x.x where x is 0-255)", :if => Proc.new {|ar| !ar.first_ip.blank? }
    validates_format_of :last_ip, :with => REG_IP, :message => "is invalid (must be x.x.x.x where x is 0-255)", :if => Proc.new {|ar| !ar.last_ip.blank? }

    def self.banned?(ip)
      reload_banned_ips if @banned_ips.nil?
      begin
          ip = Infrid::IPAddress.new(ip)
          @banned_ips.each { |b|
            return true if ip.between?(b[0], b[1])
          }
      rescue
          logger.info "IP FORMAT ERROR"
          return true
      end
      false
    end
    def self.banned_ips
        reload_banned_ips if @banned_ips.nil?
        @banned_ips.collect {|b| b[0].to_s + ".." + b[1].to_s }.join"\n"
    end
    #keeps a cache of all banned ip ranges
    def self.reload_banned_ips
      r = connection.select_all("select first_ip, last_ip from banned_ips")
      if !r
        @banned_ips=[] 
      end
      @banned_ips = r.map {|item| [Infrid::IPAddress.new(item["first_ip"]),Infrid::IPAddress.new(item["last_ip"])] }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to call `banned?` on a `String`, not on your `BannedIp` class. You have two solutions.

1. Replace the code to check for banned ip with `BannedIp.banned?(request.remote_ip)`
2. Patch in a method to the string class which calls the class method for you, which is in rails stype but less readable.

Need this here. (bug prevents code block from working)

```
class String
  def banned?
    BannedIp.banned?(self)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, BannedIP.banned?(request.remote_ip) works if write BannedIp (with 'Ip', not 'IP').

Answer (score 2):

That `request.remote_ip` returns the IP address as a String, and Strings do not have a `banned?` method. It looks like you want `BannedIP.banned?(request.remote_ip)`.

Comment: Try it, return this error:
Expected D:/IR/rails_apps/cinemato/app/models/banned_ip.rb to define BannedIP

Comment: Is the file in fact in that location?

Comment: Thanks, BannedIP.banned?(request.remote_ip) works if write BannedIp (with 'Ip', not 'IP').